# Algorithm for generating the intersection of two multisets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

A multiset is a collection of objects, some of which may be repeated. So, for example, $\{1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 7, 2\}$ is a multiset. The multiplicity of an element in a multiset is the number of times that element occurs in the multiset. Intersections of multisets can be produced in the obvious way: given multisets $A$ and $B$, the multiplicity of an element in $A∩B$ is the minimum of its multiplicities in each of $A$ and $B$.

Given $2$ finite multisets $A$ and $B$, with unordered elements (the elements could be unorderable), outline an algorithm for generating the intersection $A∩B$.

Comment: An *algorithm* in its strictest definition, will of course only be possible for finite multisets ... Maybe we should aslo impose that the elements of $A$ and $B$ are fro a universe with an - effective - order.

Comment: How can they be unorderable?  You can always assign them an order.  Any finite set can be placed in one-to-one correspondence with $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some natural number $n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I took it to mean that you don't have a sort order that you could independently apply to both $A$ and $B$